# Different solutions under distributive and commutative equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, algorithms

Given 5 numbers: $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 \in \mathbb N$

all the 4 operations: $+ - \times /$

a specific brackets pattern:

$\left(\left(\left(x_1 + x_2 \right) - x_3\right) \times x_4 \right) / x_5 = 
result$

I can permutate at will the five numbers and the 4 operations, I'm interested in the perumutations that give the same result, so with a equivalence relation such as:

> Two permutations that return the same result are said *equivalent* under the basic mathematic laws: **Commutative**, **Associative** and **Distributive**.

**Could be said that two solutions are equivalent if and only if they share the same set of numbers?**

For example, the following equations are equivalent:

```
(((142 + 350) - 372) x 125) / 15 = 1000.0
(((142 + 350) - 372) / 15) x 125 = 1000.0
```

What I mean is that the brackets are fixed but the numbers and the operator can be moved around at will.

Also, what happens if the condition changes to something like:

$
|\left(\left(\left(x_1 + x_2 \right) - x_3\right) \times x_4 \right) / x_5 - result| < \epsilon
$

Is the conjecture still Ture/False?

Would this somewhat related to a $\delta$, where $\delta$ might be:

$\delta = min(\delta_{ij}) \quad \forall i,j, \: i \ne j$

with $\delta_{ij} = |x_i - x_j|$

Or nothing could be said?

Comment: I have removed the [calculus-of-variation] and put in [algebra-precalculus] Changes may please be made if irrelevant.

Comment: I removed [algebraic-topology] and added [algorithms].

Comment: Not that I know a fast algorithm, but I would suggest to break the problem into two parts: finding all the solutions which result in the desired result, and deciding whether two solutions are equivalent (in your sense) or not.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: The first part is already "solved" *(the script I linked does exactly that)*, the second part is exactly the problem I'm facing: I'm trying to understand if two solutions are equivalent iff they share the same set of numbers, what do you think?

Comment: @RikPoggi: If that is the question, then you should have asked it.  It is much simpler than the current question.  The answer is no.  Consider two formulas (3−2)×6=6 and (6−3)×2=6.  If we forget the numbers and just consider them as (x−y)×z and (z−x)×y, they are not equivalent.  They happen to be equal because of the particular choice of the numbers.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: You're right, I'm not very good at explaining myself, I'll update my question to be more clear. Do you think that a counter-example could also be found with 5 numbers and with all (and different) 4 operations?

Comment: @Rik: Yes, append any two numbers and operators + and / to the formulas I showed, such as (((3−2)×6)+12)/9 and (((6−3)×2)+12)/9.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: Thanks! I feel a little dumb not having thought that myself. Anyway I've updated my question, and maybe you want to put your counter-example in an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is essentially my comments on the question, slightly rephrased.)

> Could be said that two solutions are equivalent if and only if they share the same set of numbers?

No, this is not true.  For example, consider two formulas (3−2)×6=6 and (6−3)×2=6.  They are not equivalent in your sense, because if we forget the numbers and just consider them as (*x*−*y*)×*z* and (*z*−*x*)×*y*, they are different in general.  They happen to be equal because of the particular choice of the numbers.

If you want a counterexample with five numbers and four operators, you can append other numbers and operators: for example, consider (((3−2)×6)+12)/9 and (((6−3)×2)+12)/9.